# Will jvm old gc mark all the heap or just olld heap?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

Will jvm old gc mark all the heap or just old heap ? Because the young generation 
 objects can contains old generation objects .

Comment: What is "old gc"?

Comment: @apangin collect old generation .

Comment: There is no collection of the old generation without collecting the young generation. So it’s the other way round, a minor gc may mark only young objects, as old objects don’t contain references to young objects, unless they were modified. And a JVM supporting such short-cut has to track modifications of old objects then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the the collector that you use.

Some collectors do not use any structure to records the references from young generation to old generation. In theory, these collectors must scan the young generation to find the garbage. However, some collectors will execute minor gc instead of scan the young generation. Like CMS(Concurrent Mark Sweep), it will scan the young generation. But you can use options

```
-XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
```

to collect young generation before doing full gc or CMS remark phase.

But some collectors don't need to scan young generation. They usually use some data structures to record the references, Like G1(Garbage First) collector. It use the RS(remember set). The G1 collector will scan the RS to find out the reference. For instance, if there is a young region call yr1, has a reference points to an object in the old region or1. The RS will add a record like:

```
yr1 -> or1
```

(The actual implementation of RS is really complicated)
So, in mark cycle, G1 will scan the RS to find out all the reference points to the or1.

More detail:

- [hotspot-virtual-machine-garbage-collection-tuning-guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/hotspot-virtual-machine-garbage-collection-tuning-guide.pdf)
- [memorymanagement-whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf)
- [G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All](https://www.infoq.com/articles/G1-One-Garbage-Collector-To-Rule-Them-All)
- [Garbage first Collection](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.63.6386&rep=rep1&type=pdf)